# unit test a Method that uses as a thread that raise event on ThreadInterruptedException c#

Tags: c#, multithreading, unit-testing, interrupted-exception

I have a Method (Play) that catch ThreadInterruptException and raise Event handler in it.
It is a static Method in a static class.

I want to test that Method by sending an interrupt to it and see if I'm getting the callback on the event.
How can I do this?
I've tried to run the code below but the callback function does not invoke.

```
public static class HelperClass{
public static EventHandler<HelperEventArgs> EvActionEndedhandler;

public class HelperEventargs: EventArgs
{
    public string ErrorMsg {get; set;}
    public int Processed {get; set;}
}

public static void Play(object o)
{
    try{
    //some code that runs in a loop
    }
    catch(ThreadInterruptedException)
    {
        EvActionEndedhandler(2, new HelperEventArgs {processed = processed});
        return;
    }
}}
```

in my test project

I'm using the visual studio unit test framework

```
[TestMethod()]

public void PlayPauseOnInterruptTest()
{
    HelperClass.EvActionEndedHandler += (sender, args) =>
    {
        if ((int)sender == 2) paused = true;
    };
}
var runningThread = new Thread(HelperClass.Play);
    try
    {
        runningThread.Start();
        if (runningThread.IsAlive)
            runningThread.Interrupt();
        while (runningThread.IsAlive)
        {
            if (paused)
            {
                Assert.IsTrue(paused);
                return;
            }
        }
        Assert.IsTrue(paused);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: `if (runningThread.IsAlive) runningThread.Interrupt();` -- I'm guessing `IsAlive` returns false when you check it, and so you never execute `Interrupt()`?

Comment: How long does `//some code that runs in a loop` run for? I just tried it with `Thread.Sleep(10000)` and the test passes.

Comment: canton7, it returns true

Comment: DaveShaw, the thing is that the loop is not sleeping and has no limited time... try to put while(true) instead

Comment: You cannot interrupt a thread if it never executes any synchronization code. `Thread.Interrupt` is a low-level method with very limited application, much like `Thread.Abort` (but not as bad). If you want cooperative cancellation, use a mechanism designed for it, like `CancellationToken` (which can be used with `Thread`s, but you may want to look at switching to `Task`s anyway). If you want non-cooperative cancellation, there's essentially no safe way to do that -- code that can be interrupted at an arbitrary point it does not control can corrupt the program state.

Comment: @JeroenMostert can you please explain :" but you may want to look at switching to Tasks anyway"

Comment: I mean using [`Task`-based asynchronous programming](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/) with `async`/`await` rather than explicit threads. It's a rather big topic. If your code is currently fully synchronous now (not using `Thread` other than to cancel synchronous code) you don't really need to go full `Task`; just passing a `CancellationToken` and checking it periodically is enough. But if you are using `Thread` to run code asynchronously, it's worth reading up on `async`/`await` and `Task.Run`.